# Как заменить считывание исходных данных с консоли на считывание из файла( за минимальное кол-во строк кода)?

Tags: c#, классы, файловая-система

Класс Транспорт:

```
abstract class Transport //: IComparable<Transport>
{
    protected string stamp;//марка
    protected int num;//номер
    protected int speed;//скорость
    public float carry;//грузоподъёмность
    public abstract void Show();
    public abstract void Carrying();

   /* public int CompareTo(Transport obj)
    {
        if (this.carry > obj.carry)
            return 1;
        if (this.carry < obj.carry)
            return -1;
        else return 0;
    }*/
}
```

Класс Легковая_машина:

```
class Passenger_car : Transport
{

    public Passenger_car(string stamp,int num,int speed,float carry)
    {
        this.stamp = stamp;
        this.num = num;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.carry = carry;
    }

    public override void Show()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Марка-{0}\tНомер-{1}\tСкорость{2}\tГрузоподъёмность{3}", stamp, num, speed, carry);
    }

    public  override void Carrying()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Грузоподъёмность = {0}",carry);
    }

}
```

Класс Мотоцикл:

```
class Motorcycle : Passenger_car
{
    public bool lulka;

    public Motorcycle(string stamp, int num, int speed, float carry,bool lulka):base(stamp,num,speed,carry)
    {
        this.lulka = lulka;

        if (this.lulka == false)
        {
            base.carry = 0;
        }

    }

    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Марка-{0}\tНомер-{1}\tСкорость{2}\tГрузоподъёмность{3}\tЕсть люлька?->{4}", stamp, num, speed, carry, lulka);
    }

    public override void Carrying()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Грузоподъёмность = {0}", carry);
    }
}
```

Класс Грузовик:

```
class Truck : Passenger_car
{
    protected bool trailer;

    public  Truck(string stamp, int num, int speed, float carry,bool trailer):base(stamp, num, speed, carry)
    {
        this.trailer = trailer;

        if (this.trailer == true)
        {
            base.carry = carry * 2;
        }

    }

    public override void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Марка-{0}\tНомер-{1}\tСкорость{2}\tГрузоподъёмность{3}\tЕсть прицеп?->{4}", stamp, num, speed, carry, trailer);
    }

    public override void Carrying()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Грузоподъёмность = {0}", carry);
    }
}
```

Главный класс:

```
 class Program 
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List <Transport> n= new List<Transport>();
        n.Add ( new Passenger_car("BMW",777,500,200));
        n.Add(new Motorcycle("KAWASAKI", 666, 350, 100,false));
        n.Add (new Truck("KAMAZ",555,60,1000,true));
        //n.Sort();


        foreach (Transport item in n)
        {
            item.Show();
            item.Carrying();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а где в приведенном коде считывание из консоли?

Comment: Что считывать из файла? Данные для создаваемых классов?

Comment: Да,для создаваемых классов

Comment: @Grundy да,ну прост не знал,как сказать :) Исходные данные занесённые статистически или бред? :)

Comment: @Bulson Нуууус есть идеи? :)

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться почему вы используете в классах методы который выводит информацию на консоль (`Show`, `Carrying`) ? Вместо метода `Show` лучше переопределить стандартный `ToString`, второй метод тоже лучше переписать так, чтобы он возвращал строку. Т.о. ваши классы будут более гибкими и вы сможете их использовать в проектах других типов.

Comment: Спасибо,изменю)

Comment: Есть такие классы как [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) и [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx), если необходимо считывать строковые данные, то лучше использовать StreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

Делаешь такой вот дженерик:

```
    public class XmlOperator<T> where T : Transport
    {
        private readonly string _filename;

        public XmlOperator(string filename)
        {
            _filename = filename;
        }


        public void SaveToXml(T[] collection)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T[]));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(_filename))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(fs, collection);
            }
        }
        public T[] GetFromXml()
        {
         if (File.Exists(_filename))
          {
            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(_filename))
                {
                    var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T[]));
                    result = (T[])x.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка загрузки " + _filename + " : " + ex.Message);
            }
          }
          return result;
        }
    }
```

Если надо XML пользоваться, то сериализуемые поля надо сделать публичными или оборачивать их публичными свойствами.
Binary на сколько помню и приватные ест.
Еще нужны публичные конструкторы по умолчанию для сериалуемых классов.

Метод Main будет какой то такой:

```
static void Main()
    {
        var cars = new List<Passenger_car>
        {
            new Passenger_car("BMW", 777, 500, 200),
            new Passenger_car("jiguli", 777777, 5, 2)
        };

        PrintItems(cars);

        var saver_loader = new XmlOperator<Passenger_car> (@"cars.xml");
        saver_loader.SaveToXml(cars.ToArray());

        var loadedCarlist = saver_loader.GetFromXml();

        PrintItems(loadedCarlist);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintItems(IEnumerable<Transport> items)
    {
        foreach (var transport in items)
        {
            transport.Show();
            transport.Carrying();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Зачем ему XML? Не стоит задача сериализации объектов в XML.

Comment: А почему бы и нет. Напишите свой вариант ответа.